# Why does this '/execute at […] run summon' command not work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make all arrows shot by the player have lightning bolts summoned on them while they are not on the ground. Here is the command:

```
/execute at @e[type=minecraft:arrow,nbt={FiredFrom:{id:player}}] run summon lightning_bolt ~ ~ ~
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I wouldn't use the `FiredFrom` nbt tag. There is an nbt tag called `inGround` that suits your purpose nicely.

You can test for all arrows that are not inGround like this:

```
execute as @e[type=arrow,nbt={inGround:0b}] run say I am not inGround
```

---

Second, your command uses `execute at`. This is a problem because `execute at` only selects one entity to run the command at. If you have multiple arrows in your world, the selected arrow may not be the one you were expecting.

To have *all* arrows summon lightning at their position, you need to use both `as` and `at`:

```
execute as @e[type=arrow,nbt={inGround:0b}] at @s run summon lightning_bolt ~ ~ ~
```

Comment: The OP wants lighting bolts when arrows are shot from players, not just any. Also the part about the `execute at` is entirely false, it does work on all entites; Any command that only uses one enity (such as `data`) will force you to use `limit=1`

Answer (score 0):

The FiredFrom nbt tag doesn't exist. I'll make this as simple as possible with possible flaws; the `pickup` nbt is set to 1b when shot by players and dispenser, but not by creative players nor skeletons.

`/execute at @e[type=minecraft:arrow,nbt={pickup:1b,inGround:0b}] run summon minecraft:lightning_bolt`

I'll give the idea of a more elaborate answer but I wont go on details unless ask for it. You'd want to execute at every player who has recently shot with a bow/crossbow (using scoreboards), and tag the closest arrow. The do the previous command but checking for that tag.